# Looking for a webcam what works with Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, webcam

I have recently bought an A4TECH PK-1000HA webcam and though it's a brilliant piece of hardware, its use on Ubuntu was anything but comfortable.

So I am looking for a webcam for videoconference/business use, that:

- is proven to have good compatibility with Linux (Ubuntu in particular)
- doesn't support wide-angle (77-78 degrees is good enough)
- have a physical shutter for privacy
- doesn't have any integrated backlight (it's being switched on even when the camera is not active, which is annoying)
- is a good fit for videoconference/business use

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The one I found on https://www.bol.com/be/nl/p/webcam-full-hd-1080p-webcam-met-microfoon-usb-autofocus-thuiswerken-webcam-voor-pc-zwart-windows-mac/9300000010145823/ has everything except one, the shutter, but you can achieve that by unplugging the usb cable. Because it doesn't have any drivers, it will probably work with Linux without much setup.